# Add days to unix timestamp value in where statement

Tags: php, mysql, unix-timestamp

I have a date stored in a table called `grids` in a field called  `g_date_created`. It's stored as a unix timestamp. I want to select all rows from `grids` that have a `g_date_created` plus X numbers of days between a certain time range.

For example:

```
Select * FROM grids 
WHERE g_date_created + 3 days BETWEEN timestamp_1 AND timestamp_2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select * FROM grids 
WHERE g_date_created + interval 3 day BETWEEN timestamp_1 AND timestamp_2
```

Comment: That did it, thanks. Just had to changed days to "day"

Comment: Sorry, does this work if timestap_1 and timestamp_2 are unix timestamps or do i need to use from_unixtime on them also?

Comment: I just tried it myself - looks like you don't need the  `from_timestamp` at all:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15b68/4